# how do i make an fx declaration a global variable in flex?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, global-variables, flash-builder

I've been trying to make my declaration to be a global variable. I think its possible but I just dont know how to do it.

```
<fx:XML id = list source="data/abut.xml"/>
```

`

```
        protected function addRec():void{
            prefsFile = File.applicationStorageDirectory;
            prefsFile = prefsFile.resolvePath("data/abut.xml"); 
            var outputString:String = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n';
            var xml:XML = 
                <emp>
                <name>{neym.text}</name>
                <age>{age.text}</age>
                <birth>{bday.selectedDate}</birth>
                <cont>{cnum.text}</cont>
                <email>{email.text}</email>
                <nbi>{nbi.text}</nbi>
                <postal>{postal.text}</postal>
                <dl>{dl.text}</dl>
                <sss>{sss.text}</sss>
                <pid>{pid.text}</pid>
                <vid>{vid.text}</vid>
                <prc>{prc.text}</prc>
                <bir>{bir.text}</bir>
                <tin>{tin.text}</tin>
                </emp>;
            list = list.appendChild(xml);
            outputString += list.toXMLString();
            outputString = outputString.replace(/\n/g, File.lineEnding);
            stream.open(prefsFile, FileMode.WRITE);
            stream.writeUTFBytes(outputString);
            stream.close();
            trace(outputString);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>`
```

I want to update my existing xml file but it throws an error, I don't know what to do can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

pls send more details about error that you have, and also change that:`<fx:XML id="list" source="data/abut.xml"/>`
Check xml content with `trace(list);` 
The variable 'list' should not be declared in the code.